# How to execute a pre-saved dql string

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

let's say for some reason I have a DQL string saved somewhere (in the DB) along with the necessary parameters, can I set it in a queryBuilder object and execute it?
I expected to be able to so something like

```
$builder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $builder->getQuery()
            ->setDQL($stringDql)
            ->setParameters($arrayParams);
return $query->iterate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity manager has `::createQuery(string $dql);` Where there string of DQL comes from it would not care.

```
$dql = 'SELECT u FROM MyProject\Model\User u WHERE u.age > 20';
// $dql = $this->getQueryFromDatabase();
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
```